# ImageDataGenerator error

Tags: python, keras

I need help trying to fix this code for a simple autoencoder in Keras. I was trying to add some image preprocessing for the autoencoder tutorial on the Keras blog. This is what I've done

```
input_image = Input(shape=(1,256,256,))
flattened = Flatten()(input_image)
encoded = Dense(128,activation='relu',name='Dense1')(flattened)
decoded = Dense(256*256, activation='sigmoid',name='Dense2')(encoded)
output_image = Reshape((1,256,256,))(decoded)
autoencoder = Model(input_image,output_image)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='binary_crossentropy')

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rotation_range=20,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)

autoencoder.fit_generator(datagen.flow(train_imgs, train_imgs,
            batch_size=32),
            samples_per_epoch=train_imgs.shape[0],
            nb_epoch=50,
            validation_data=(test_imgs,test_imgs))
```

`train_imgs` has shape (1000,256,256) where 1000 is the number of training samples. `test_imgs` has shape(50,256,256).

This is the error I got

> Exception: output of generator should be a tuple (x, y, sample_weight)
>   or (x, y). Found: None

This was raised by the `fit_generator` function.

Answer (score 4):

Figured this thing out myself. Turns out that ImageDataGenerator assumes that the input is in the shape (number_of_samples,number_of_channels,width,height). 
Reshaping `train_imgs` and `test_imgs` did the trick. I have modified the code in the question to include this extra dimension.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change class_mode to 'input' like this :

```
autoencoder.fit_generator(datagen.flow(train_imgs, train_imgs,
        batch_size=32,class_mode='input'),
        samples_per_epoch=train_imgs.shape[0],
        nb_epoch=50,
        validation_data=(test_imgs,test_imgs))
```

You can read more [here](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/pull/6510)

Answer (score -1):

I think you have forgotten to fit the datagen model. Please add `datagen.fit(train_imgs)` before `autoencoder.fit_generator` and try to train your model.